# Best Indexing technique for a table that does SELECT WHERE on different columns

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, query-optimization, where-clause

I'm looking to achieve efficient indexing technique for my logs table that looks like this:

```
MariaDB [Webapp]> explain logs;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| activity_name  | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activity_key   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activity_value | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| activity_date  | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

I do searching like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE user_id IN (1, 3)
  AND activity_name IN ('login', 'logout')
  AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01'
  AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

Where columns `user_id`, `activity_name` and `activity_date` are involved

---

And sometimes like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE user_id IN (1, 3)
  AND activity_name IN ('login', 'logout')
```

Where both `user_id` and `activity_name` are involved but no date.

---

And like this too:

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE user_id IN (1, 3)
  AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01'
  AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
WHERE activity_name IN ('login', 'logout')
  AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01'
  AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

I did read about **Compound Indexes** and that they would be good if my search was ordered, but as you can see it's not so I think its not suitable..

And I also read that **single index** can be used just on one column at once, so i think it won't be good for my case..

Any ideas please, I'm not too much familiar with MySQL. How can I make my queries optimal?

**Note**: I don't use the wildcard **(*)** because I read it slow down things but I just put it to shorten the query for easier understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each query, the base idea is to have an index whose columns cover the `where` clause. For your This cannot be achieved using a single index for the four queries - I think that you need 3 indexes.

First, consider the following index:

```
logs(user_id, activity_name, activity_date)
```

It matches on the `where` clause of the first query:

```
WHERE 
    user_id IN (1, 3) 
    AND activity_name IN ('login', 'logout') 
    AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01' 
    AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

And also on the second query (the third index column is ignored here):

```
WHERE 
    user_id IN (1, 3) 
    AND activity_name IN ('login', 'logout')
```

For the two other queries, you need two separate indexes:

```
WHERE 
    user_id IN (1, 3) 
    AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01' 
    AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

Needs:

```
logs(user_id, activity_date)
```

And:

```
WHERE 
    activity_name IN ('login', 'logout') 
    AND activity_date >= '2020-02-01' 
    AND activity_date <= '2020-06-01'
```

Needs:

```
logs(activity_name, activity_date)
```

Side note: in general, do not blindly `select *`; instead, enumerate the columns you want in the result set - especially if you don't want them all. If you just need two or three columns, consider adding them at the end of the index, hence turning it to a *covering* index.

Comment: Also keep in mind that after the first column used in a range condition, the subsequent columns of the index are not used for searching or sorting. The best you can hope for is [index condition pushdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html) which is better than having no help from the index, but not as good as index filtering.